# My WHERE clause is not showing when I put equal to a value

Tags: sql, where-clause

So when I put this code everything works except for the end_station_name as it shows all end_station_name, not just "Toomey Rd @ South Lamar" how I want to. Why is that?

```
SELECT 
subscriber_type , duration_minutes , end_station_name, start_station_name
FROM 
bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
 WHERE (subscriber_type = "Walk Up") OR (subscriber_type = "24-Hour Kiosk (Austin B-cycle)") 
 AND end_station_name = "Toomey Rd @ South Lamar"
 ORDER BY duration_minutes DESC
```

Comment: Your parenthesis is non-functional, you need to add parenthesis around both `or` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the AND operator has precedence over OR.
Can you try to put the first 2 conditions which use  OR in a bracket

```
WHERE ( (subscriber_type = "Walk Up") OR (subscriber_type = "24-Hour Kiosk (Austin B-cycle)") )AND end_station_name = "Toomey Rd @ South Lamar"
```